# How to represent list of objects as an array of json objects

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, arraylist, data-structures

I am writing a web application using java, and the spring mvc framework.
(I would like to specify a number of points and then have google maps plot it on a map).

In my java Controller, I build up list of objects, and then return it to my client code, via the ModelAndView.

In my View, I then access this list as follows:

```
  <h1>List of Geo-Location points: </h1>

  <c:forEach items="${mapcontent}" var="point">
    ${point.latitude} ${point.longitude} ${point.message}
    <br />
  </c:forEach>
```

I am quite happy with the result, as it prints out all my relevant results. 
like this:

```
    33.9249 18.4241 This is a message 
    34.9249 18.4241 This is another a message 
    35.9249 18.4241 This is a quick message
```

Moving to my current difficulty, I need to give this incoming data, in the following format:

```
    var markers = [
    {
      coordinates:{lat:-33.9811688, lng:18.644},
      message: 'Task completed at Stellenbosch Station'
    },
    {
      coordinates:{lat:-33.9811688, lng:19.644},
      message: 'Please report for duty'
    }
    ]
```

My question therefore is how to go from the list of objects send from the server, to an array of json objects, in java script.

```
  // taglib solution that I am currently trying:
  Using taglib:
  <%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
  <h1>List of Geo-Location points: </h1>

  <c:forEach items="${mapcontent}" var="point">
    <!-- ${point.name} ${point.telephoneNumber} ${point.genericDateTime} -->

    <json:object>
      <json:array name="coordinates" var="coordinate" items="${point.coordinates}">
        <json:object>
          <json:property name="latitude" value="${item.latitude}"/>
          <json:property name="longitude" value="${item.longitude}"/>
        </json:object>
      </json:array>
    </json:object>
    <json:property name="message" value="${point.genericDateTime}"/>


  </c:forEach>
```

Danke!

Comment: You need a JSON parser, such as Jackson. By the way, you should show us what your _list of objects_ looks like.

Comment: I've updated the post with the list of objects

Answer (score 0):

Faced with it before. I found json-taglib for that purpose.

http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/

Maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/atg.taglib.json/json-taglib/0.4.1

Comment: Hi @Alex - I have looked at the json-taglib example provided on the linked page. I have come up with some code (see original post question), but I do not know how to proceed from there. What is the object containing the json structure, and can I just initialise my marker with it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the result of <json:object> will be a simple string in json format

Comment: Am I doing it right by placing the code block into the existing forEach loop? Is that necessary.

Comment: In order to avoid c:forEach, use <json:array items="${mapcontent} .....">
                 <json:object .......>